Missing Bullet Inverse Dynamics while building tesseract-collision
I am trying to build the tesseract motion planning environment for ROS, but I am running into the following error while building the tesseract-collision package using catkin: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lBULLET_LIB_ABS_BulletInverseDynamics-float64-NOTFOUND
I installed the libbullet-dev and libbullet-extras-dev packages on Ubuntu focal, but this did not solve the problem. What else can I try?
